# Why Renault megane II 1.4 has so much electrical problems

Tags: electrical, renault, megane

I recently bought a megane II 1.4 petrol 2006 about 140,000km.
I am the second owner of the car, I only fixed rear window i havent done anything to car since i bought it.

I have driven it for about 4-5 months.

**My problem** is with A/C It's currently not working I need to move the cables for it to work but after few min its back to not working, I would like to fix it locally rather than Going to the mechanic I think there is a easy fix to this problem, Also I have back sensors in this car but they havent been working since I bought the car, When I press the button  the light works on the button but the sensor don't.

PS. I havent got alot of experienced in fixing cars just know how to do the usual change oil,brakes etc. more of a computer guy :)

Comment: Welcome to this stack. What year is the car, and did you buy it new? Also, have you done anything to the car? Phantom problems like this can have a *lot* of possible causes, so if you can include *as much data as possible* that will help us help you.

Comment: @kyle_engineer I have updated my question

Comment: "Why does the Megane have so many electrical problems" is not really a useful question here. There are various cars with much worse track record - when googling for problems you do get a lot of confirmation bias, as no-one posts up loud messages on how faultless their car is. Do you have a problem with it that we can help you with?

Comment: @RoryAlsop I was just wondering why this model has so many problems, But Yes Currently i have a problem with A/C It does not work , I have to move the cables for it to work but after few min its back to not working if you know what I mean, How could i fix it locally instead of goin to the mechanic?

Comment: Okay - I'd suggest editing your question to just have: type of of car, problem you are encountering, and what you have tried. That way it can be answered here. Thanks.

Comment: @RoryAlsop ive update my answer